# Is it possible to create a flat short line in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Yesterday I was trying to create an indicator that creates a short line, in H1 candles.

Something like the Standard Pivot Point on TradingView.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VfAeCvc.png this is the link of the example, sorry

Comment: You can draw horizontal lines but you can't not use variables for that (then it wouldn't be a straight horizontal line).

Comment: i need to create a line like the example, so basically is not possible? with Pine Script

Comment: You can draw a horizontal line if you have a constant variable (e.g. a user input). Otherwise, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

I have my implementation of pivot points where I draw some lines. Maybe that's not exactly what you're asking for, but I hope it'll be heplful for you:

```
//@version=3
study("Pivot Points, Traditional (today)", overlay=true)
daylyClose = security(tickerid, "D", close)
daylyHigh = security(tickerid, "D", high)
daylyLow = security(tickerid, "D", low)

pivot = (daylyClose + daylyHigh + daylyLow) / 3


r1 = pivot * 2 - daylyLow
r2 = pivot + (daylyHigh - daylyLow)
r3 = pivot * 2 + (daylyHigh - 2 * daylyLow)
r4 = pivot * 3 + (daylyHigh - 3 * daylyLow)
r5 = pivot * 4 + (daylyHigh - 4 * daylyLow)


s1 = pivot * 2 - daylyHigh
s2 = pivot - (daylyHigh - daylyLow)
s3 = pivot * 2 - (2 * daylyHigh - daylyLow)
s4 = pivot * 3 - (3 * daylyHigh - daylyLow)
s5 = pivot * 4 - (4 * daylyHigh - daylyLow)


plot(pivot, style= stepline)
plot(r1, style= stepline)
plot(r2, style= stepline)
plot(r3, style= stepline)
plot(r4, style= stepline)
plot(r5, style= stepline)

plot(s1, style= stepline)
plot(s2, style= stepline)
plot(s3, style= stepline)
plot(s4, style= stepline)
plot(s5, style= stepline)
```

[image]

Note1: my script works for intraday resolution - on daily resolutions it gets changed every day.

Note2: That's only works for existing bars - history and realtime. It cannot draw a line to the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can also plot shorter horizontal lines by using the `plot()` function and changing the color to `na` (to "hide" the plotted line)

```
//@version=2
study("Horizontal line", overlay=false)
counter = nz(counter[1]) == 6 ? 0 : nz(counter[1]) + 1
line_color = counter < 5 ? orange : na

plot(10, color=line_color)
```

The `nz(counter[1])` looks at the previous value (1 step back) of the `counter` series and the `nz()` function returns `0.0` in case there is no previous value of `counter` (e.g. at the beginning of the market)

You can overlay this over the candle chart by changing the `overlay` parameter of `study()` to `true`.
This is great in some cases, but unfortunately it causes problems with the automatic scale if you set the value of your line to `0` or `na`, because the plotted line is still there, even though is invisible. I'm usually setting the value to `close` or `open` to work around this.